# How To Apply Multiple MAT_DATE_FORMATS On Same Component

Tags: angular, datepicker, formatting, angular-material

I have a component that contains many date inputs. All of them, but one, will use the standard format (MM/DD/YYYY). I read [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats), which helped me figure out how to get the customFormat (MM/YYYY) I wanted, but now it shows on every date input because of the provider 'useValue' on the component level. Which lead me to this question I cannot find a proper answer for. How can I have multiple formats on the same component?

**On the TypeScript:**

```
    export const COMMISSION_DATE_FORMATS = {
      parse: {
        dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
      },
      display: {
        dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
        monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
      },
    };
...    
    providers: [
        { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
        { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS , useValue: COMMISSION_DATE_FORMATS },
      ]
```

**On the UI:**

One requiring custom format (displays properly)

```
  <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dSaleMonthPicker" placeholder="Commission Month & Year" formControlName="dSaleMonth">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dSaleMonthPicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #dSaleMonthPicker startView="multi-year" (yearSelected)="commissionDateYearHandler($event)" (monthSelected)="commissionDateMonthHandler($event, dSaleMonthPicker)">
        </mat-datepicker>
     </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

Others requiring standard format (but they are also displaying with custom format)

```
  <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput formControlName="dSold" [matDatepicker]="dSoldPicker" placeholder="Sold Date" matTooltipPosition="below">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dSoldPicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #dSoldPicker [startAt]="dSold"></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

I know with the formControlName I can't use typical "piping" from Angular, so how can I have multiple formats on the same component? Perhaps there is a way to add the custom format directly on the input? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Briana, have you found a solution for this? I'm facing the same challenge. Cheers!

Comment: I too have the same issue. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50616721/two-datepickers-on-angular-material-with-different-date-format) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I found the best answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62814736/6895106). Basically, we need to create multiple directives with different formats and attach the desired directive to the datepicker.

Working example with MomentDateAdapter can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azrzg5?file=app%2Fdatepicker-moment-example.ts) (thanks to [Abishek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7702096/abishek-amstrong) from above link).

Working example with NativeDateAdapter can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qw6uvp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-formats.directive.ts)